# How to grep for files containing a specific word and pass the list of files as argument to second command?

Tags: unix, grep

```
grep rli "stringName" * | xargs <second_command> <list_of files>
```

will the above code work for the functionality mentioned?

I am a beginner to not sure how to use it.

Comment: Have you thought about executing the command?

Comment: If *second_command* may only run once, you have a problem if `grep` returns more files than `xargs` can fit into a single command line; then *second_command* will be run multiple times on slices of the entire list. If *second_command* can read a list of files, like `grep -f -` or `zip -@`, that's a good workaround.

Comment: You lack the option dash before `-rli`. Also `*` is redundant with `-r`; just feed it the current direcory `.` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing hyphen for options to `grep`. Following should work

```
grep -rli "stringName" * | xargs <second_command>
```

Considering above command cannot handle whitespace or weird characters in file names, more robust solution would be to use `find`

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qi "stringName" {} + -print0 | xargs -0 <second_command>
```

Or use `-Z` option with `xargs -0`

```
grep -rli "stringName" * -Z | xargs -0 <second_command>
```

Comment: +1 for a perfectly correct solution. (Something that is rarely found).

Comment: `-qli` makes no sense. `-qi` is enough

Comment: @JoSo glad that you found it useful. thanks for pointing that out. updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on jkshah's answer, which is already quite good.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qi "regex" {} \; -exec "second_command" {} \;
```

This has the advantage of being more portable (`-print0` and `-0` are gnu extensions).

It executes the second command for each matching file in turn. If you want to execute with a list of all matching files at the end instead, change the last `\;` to `+`

Comment: I found that `-print0` is supported in [**BSD find**](http://real-world-systems.com/docs/find-bsd.html) also. Even `-0` in [**BSD xargs**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jkshah, I just like to restrict on POSIX features. It's cleaner.